# Shared storage premission on Android TV

Tags: java, android, android-tv

my app requires Shared storage access, it does so using this code

```
StorageManager manager = (StorageManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = manager.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();
            String targetDirectory = ""; // Root
            Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");
            String scheme = uri.getScheme();
            scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/tree");
            scheme += "%3A" + targetDirectory;
            uri = Uri.parse(scheme);

            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);

            startActivityForResult(intent, MY_PERMISSIONS_GRANT_SHARED_STORAGE);
```

Everything works fine on phone & tablet.
But my app is also made to work on Android TV where i get a message saying "You don't have an app that can do this" (Android emulator)

I guess Android TV does not have OpenDocumentTreeIntent... so my question would be - how to make this work?

Media storage is not an answer - i need to use Shared storage..
Thank you!

Comment: As far as i remember `createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()` can only be used on Android N, O and P. So has not much to do with TV or not.

Comment: But why not use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?

Comment: Because I'm not trying to onetime-open folder. I need to grant permission for a home folder for an app and than read files from that base folder..

Comment: Well then that action is just what you need. You can take permission for all time